# Getting current user ID in a custom block

Tags: 8, blocks

I have a custom block where I need to use `[current-user:uid]` in just one text. In Drupal 7, I would have used `PHP input filter`. How can I do this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [twig bamboo](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/bamboo-twig/usage#s-loaders) or a preprocess function where you load the current user.

```
function hook_preprocess_HOOK(&$variables) {
  $vars['user'] = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());}
```